# Loop through multiple files in a directory and save into a single excel file in different sheets

Tags: python, pandas

I have a group of csv files saved into a folder that I want to loop through, convert into a pandas dataframe, perform a series of operations, than save into a single Excel file with each dataframe saved into it's own sheet.

This is my code so far.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

dir_b = r'/Desktop/MyProjects'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Compiled File.xlsx')

for csv in Path(dir_b).glob('*.csv'):
    df_list = []
    df = pd.read_csv(csv, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', engine='python', delimiter = ',')
    car_column = df.pop('car')
    df.insert(9, 'car', car_column)
    df_list.append(df)
    for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet' + str(i+1), index = False)
writer.save()
```

Everything seems to work expect the saving into the Excel file. There is no error when I run the code, but the final Excel file only shows 1 sheet from only 1 dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You are emptying your array each iteration. Try this:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

dir_b = r'/Desktop/MyProjects'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Compiled File.xlsx')


df_list = []
for csv in Path(dir_b).glob('*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', engine='python', delimiter = ',')
    car_column = df.pop('car')
    df.insert(9, 'car', car_column)
    df_list.append(df)

for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet' + str(i+1), index = False)
        writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `df_list` definition should be outside the for loop. Or else, it will get emptied for every iteration -

```
df_list = []
for csv in Path(dir_b).glob('*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', engine='python', delimiter = ',')
    car_column = df.pop('car')
    df.insert(9, 'car', car_column)
    df_list.append(df)
    for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Sheet' + str(i+1), index = False)
writer.save()
```